# How to add Dvorak in Debian greeter of installation media CD/USB?

Tags: debian, keyboard-layout, tails-os, dvorak

I want to contribute a patch to this feature request [Consider adding Dvorak in the default keyboard layout option list in the greeter](https://labs.riseup.net/code/issues/12331) in Tails OS so I am thinking how to do it in Debian 8.7 first. 
I do not understand precisely how you can make such a change in the existing USB Live media.

I do know how to make a persistent live system as in the thread [How do I make a persistent live USB of Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/768970/25388) but how to make a change in the existing live installation media is unknown to me because

- There is an installation code in apt-get which creates the installation on USB. It is using some codes. How can you study those codes which is about the keyboard layout in the greeter?
- ...

OS current: Debian 8.7
OS target: Tails OS

Comment: Install the `console-data` package then run `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` select "Select keymap ..." then dvorak

Comment: How can you make a patch about the change?